# C#: Strange characters on Treeview

Tags: c#, xml, treeview

I have a question about Treeview.
At the output of the nodes, strange node names appear. I don't know why.

[image]

```
  private void AddTreeViewNode(TreeNodeCollection trv_nodes, XmlNode xml_node)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(xml_node.Name);

        TreeNode new_node = trv_nodes.Add(xml_node.name);
        foreach(XmlNode child_node in xml_node.ChildNodes)
        {
            AddTreeViewNode(new_node.Nodes, 
    }
```

Comment: It is the encoding.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: Check the usage/presence of a Byte Order Mark (BOM) in the XML file as well as the encoding

Comment: I changed the name in the code and nothing changed.

Comment: To help you, I think we will need to see a [mcve], specifically a sample of the XML and how you are loading it into an `XmlDocument`.  As mentioned above, it's probably the encoding.